why does git keep trying to push my cache folder if i have it in the .gitignore?
it doesn't show up when i run git ls-tree --name-only <branch>, but when i try to push it says
remote: error: File cache/win64/nw.zip is 140.68 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File cache/win64/nwjs-sdk-v0.89.0-win-x64/nw.dll is 220.50 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File cache/win64/nw.zip is 162.40 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB
remote: error: File cache/osx64/nw.zip is 132.53 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

and it has an error for each folder in cache
i have /cache* in the .gitignore and i even ran git rm -r --cached cache to make sure its not already tracking it. i also increased the http.postBuffer to 1gb

Are you specifying the branch when you push? Perhaps it is trying to push multiple branches and a different one has the problem.

ya. i run git push origin equip

even git-lfs isnt working. i was able to merge the other branch with main locally, but i cant push.

Is the cache folder in the root of the repository? If it's not, then your ignore syntax may not work. Often it's better to specify a folder in .gitignore as
cache/
rather than
/cache*
That way it will work regardless of whether it's in the root folder or not.

it is in the root. doing cache/ didnt work either. i ended up just moving the folder to my desktop, pushing it, then putting it back. i get the same error. about the same folders that no longer exist
